# Firebase Blaze Compiler Gives Incorrect Results

Tags: firebase

I am trying to compile a `rules.json` for the following [Blaze](https://github.com/firebase/blaze_compiler) YAML file:

```
functions:
  - isLoggedIn(): auth.id !== null

schema:
    type: object
    properties:
        projects:
            type: object
            $projectId:
                type: object
                properties:
                    roles:
                        type: object
                        $permissionId:
                            type: object
                            $roleId: {type: boolean}

access:
  - location: /projects/$projectId/
    write: isLoggedIn() && (!next.exists() || next.hasChildren())
```

When I compile it with blaze I get the following JSON:

```
{
  "rules":{
    ".write":"false",
    ".read":"false",
    "projects": {
      ".write":"false",
      ".read":"false",
      "$projectId": {
        ".write":"(((false)))",
        ".read":"false",
        "roles": {
          ".write":"((false))",
          ".read":"false",
          "$permissionId": {
            ".write":"((false))",
            ".read":"false",
            "$roleId": {
              ".write":"(((!newData.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().exists()||!(((newData.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().isString()||newData.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().isNumber()||newData.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().isBoolean()))))&&(!newData.parent().parent().parent().parent().exists()||!(((newData.parent().parent().parent().parent().isString()||newData.parent().parent().parent().parent().isNumber()||newData.parent().parent().parent().parent().isBoolean()))))&&(!newData.parent().parent().parent().exists()||!(((newData.parent().parent().parent().isString()||newData.parent().parent().parent().isNumber()||newData.parent().parent().parent().isBoolean()))))&&(!newData.parent().parent().exists()||!(((newData.parent().parent().isString()||newData.parent().parent().isNumber()||newData.parent().parent().isBoolean()))))&&(!newData.parent().exists()||!(((newData.parent().isString()||newData.parent().isNumber()||newData.parent().isBoolean()))))&&(!newData.exists()||newData.isBoolean())&&auth.id!==null&&(!newData.parent().parent().parent().exists()||newData.parent().parent().parent().hasChildren())))",
              ".read":"false"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would have expected the `$projectId.write` rule to contain the compiled version of `isLoggedIn() && (!next.exists() || next.hasChildren())` but instead it contains `(((false)))`.

Is this a bug in blaze or are my YAML rules not constructed correctly? If it is not correct, where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not a bug but some subtleties related to nesting of wildchilds. "The use of a wildchild prevents all ascendents from being writable." [1]

You can use a wilderchild instead on the $projectId by "~$projectId" (note that comes with some security considerations, you won't be able to prevent logged in users from deleting $permissionId records[2])

```
functions:
  - isLoggedIn(): auth.id !== null

schema:
    type: object
    properties:
        projects:
            type: object
            ~$projectId:
                type: object
                properties:
                    roles:
                        type: object
                        $permissionId:
                            type: object
                            $roleId: {type: boolean}

access:
  - location: /projects/$projectId/
    write: isLoggedIn() && (!next.exists() || next.hasChildren())
```

[1] https://github.com/firebase/blaze_compiler#wildchild

[2] https://github.com/firebase/blaze_compiler#wilderchild

Comment: I missed that point from the docs. Thanks for the clarification.